# Cartopy unable to find tilematrix for projection

Tags: python, wmts, cartopy

I am currently trying to run the example script from cartopy

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io.shapereader import FionaReader
import os
import fiona


def main():
    url = 'http://localhost:8080/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml'
    layer = 'LayerName'
    print(os.getcwd())

    fig = plt.figure()
   
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.epsg('3857'))

    ax.add_wmts(url, layer)
    #ax.set_extent([-15, 25, 35, 60], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    ax.set_title('Suomi NPP Earth at night April/October 2012')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As a server I use mapproxy with wmts. The Error message is :

```
ValueError: Unable to find tile matrix for projection.
    Projection: _EPSGProjection(3857)
    Available tile CRS URNs:
        EPSG:3857
        EPSG:900913
```

I found a similar problem with no answer yet : https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently,  cartopy couldn't work with the EPSG Codes my server was sending back to it. While in debug mode, I could see that it was never able to set any tilematrix_set

To Solve the problem import:

```
import cartopy.io.ogc_clients as ogcc
```

Then adding this two lines before calling the `add_wmts` function:

```
ogcc.METERS_PER_UNIT['EPSG:3857'] = 1
ogcc._URN_TO_CRS['EPSG:3857'] = ccrs.GOOGLE_MERCATOR
```

This adds the return values of my server to the dictonary of cartopy.